# Embedded facebook video doesn't show up

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a facebook video to embed within a webview on my mobile app. The video never shows up. I tried to simplify this and move it to an html page that I can see the developer console on. All the html is there, but the video iframe never shows up. I've tried just copying in the facebook video example and it does the same thing. I can see the blockquote, but thats all that is visible. I don't see any errors in the console, I tried looking through fiddler and didn't see anything, so I'm not sure whats going on. Here is what I have:

```
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-video" data-
href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-
width="500" data-show-text="false">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<blockquote 
cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/">
<a 
href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/">How to 
Share With Just Friends</a>
<p>How to share with just friends.</p>
Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/">Facebook</a> on 
Friday, December 5, 2014
</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
  });
};
```

and if loaded asynchronous:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Afaik you can delete the line with the appId. It's just for facebook tracking.